# Programmatically open markdown-preview in Atom when opening a markdown file

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

### What I want to do

When I open a [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) file, I want [Atom](https://atom.io) to automatically toggle the [markdown-preview](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) mode.

### What I did so far

**Content of my init.coffee file:**

```
atom.workspace.onDidAddPaneItem (event) ->
    if event.item.getGrammar().name is 'GitHub Markdown'
        atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'markdown-preview:toggle')
```

### What could help to solve the problem

If the markdown file tab is open and I run the `atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'markdown-preview:toggle')` command, it will work.

I think there are 2 possible approaches to do this, I juste need to figure out how to do this:

- Switch current tab to the one displaying the markdown file and run the toggle command

OR

- Get the markdown tab and apply the toggle command

Here is the [Atom API](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.0.10/Atom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package **markdown-preview-opener** automatically open files.

https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-opener

Comment: Hey thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.